# Two actions from one button in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to activate an iOS Notification Center timer and simultaneously send a user to a web URL (in actuality a survey).  I can't figure out how to get the two actions from a single button.  Here is the code I have that currently uses two separate buttons:

```
@IBAction func timer(_ sender: Any)
{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Reminder"
    content.subtitle = "Click This Notice"
    content.body = "Please Repeat Daily"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 86400, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

@IBAction func survey(_ sender: Any) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "https://yahoo.com"){ UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated as I am a less than basic programmer.

Comment: Use button.tag properties

Comment: Why not doing `@IBAction func buttonAction(_sender:Any) {self.timer(sender); self.survey(sender)}`?

Comment: You could simply connect your Button to _both_  targets (= both `@IBAction`s) in Interface Builder or in code with `addTarget(_:action:for:)`

Answer (score 1):

From the Storyboard you can simply cntrl drag from your button to your View Controller.  Select action and name action1.. or whatever.

Do this a second time for action2

Implement your two actions and you are done.  When you click the button, both actions will be called.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your button target may look like:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timer(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Just call the second method from inside the first method:

```
@objc func timer(_ sender: Any) {
    print("timer")
    survey(sender)
}
@objc func survey(_ sender: Any) {
    print("survey")
}
```

Just pass the button as the argument for the second method's parameter.

Comment: Thanks slickdaddy, your method was pretty simple and works fine!